# Predict values for missing data in r

Tags: r

I am working on a data set that has 1008 total observations and I remove the missing cases to create the linear model. The training set now has 937 total observations.

The code I used to create my lm is below:

```
lm.data <- lm(N001S009P088.Average.Horizontal.Wind.Speed.RG.6 ~ C01.Average.Wind.Speed.48.5m+
            C02.Average.Wind.Speed.48.5m+ C03.Average.Wind.Speed.40.0m+
            C05.Average.Wind.Speed.15.0m+ N002S007P004.Average.Pressure..mb.+ 
            N001S007P006.Average.wind.speed,
          data=complete.data)
```

I am now trying to go back and predict the missing values from the original dataset using the lm from the training set.

```
all.data$Expected.RG.6.Average.Wind.Speed <- predict(lm.data)
```

When I run this process I get the following error message:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Expected.RG.6.Average.Wind.Speed",  : 
  replacement has 947 rows, data has 1008

These predicted values will plotted against the actual values to see how effective th linear model is in its prediction.

Additionally, the entire column is filled with missing data values.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this link helps http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95832/missing-values-nas-in-the-test-data-when-using-predict-lm-in-r

Comment: Putting in predicted outcomes with no description of the ultimate uses to which this effort might be used seems statistically suspect. If you intend to now runs some sort of confirmatory analysis on this autmented, some might say distorted or falsified dataset, then we should wish you nothing but bad luck.

Comment: This project is for a course I am currently enrolled in; and it is using wind measurements from the Great Lakes. The end purpose of the project is to find the predicted values and plot them against the actual values.

Comment: In the absence of a reproducible example I would guess that you should use the `newdata` parameter of `predict`.

Comment: You are trying to predict for all 947 values, and append it to the whole dataset of 1008. Use `newdata` to pass in only rows with missing values. Use the same filter to subset the original `complete.data` to insert the result.